# how to fix auto height problem in deep level tableView?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating deep level tableView (main tableView has two cells, which also have tableViews and they also have other tableViews)

Number of tableViews and cells is limited (it means i don't need recursion)

For rowHeights i'm using UITableView.automaticDimension, but it doesn't works properly.

Here is a screenshot from storyboard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JARb.jpg

And this is a result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvx9t.jpg

class TipsCountriesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tipsCountriesTableView: TipsCountriesTableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tipsCountriesHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    tipsCountriesTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let obj = object as? UITableView {
        if obj == tipsCountriesTableView && keyPath == "contentSize" {
            if let newSize = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize {
                tipsCountriesHeightConstraint.constant = tipsCountriesTableView.contentSize.height
            }
        }
    }
}

deinit {
    self.tipsCountriesTableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}
```

}

class TipsCitiesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tipsCitiesTableView: TipsCitiesTableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tipsCitiesHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    tipsCitiesTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let obj = object as? UITableView {
        if obj == tipsCitiesTableView && keyPath == "contentSize" {
            if let newSize = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize {
                tipsCitiesHeightConstraint.constant = tipsCitiesTableView.contentSize.height
            }
        }
    }
}

deinit {
    self.tipsCitiesTableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}
```

}

class TipsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tipsTableView: TipsTableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tipsTableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    tipsTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let obj = object as? UITableView {
        if obj == tipsTableView && keyPath == "contentSize" {
            if let newSize = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize {
                tipsTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tipsTableView.contentSize.height
            }
        }
    }
}

deinit {
    self.tipsTableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}
```

}

```
class TipsContinentsTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var data: [ItineraryTipsContinent]?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard indexPath.row == 0 else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TipsCountriesTableViewCell") as! TipsCountriesTableViewCell
            cell.tipsCountriesTableView.data = data?[indexPath.section].countries
            return cell
        }
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TipsTableViewCell") as! TipsTableViewCell
        cell.tipsTableView.data = data?[indexPath.section].tips
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeaderView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "TravelInfoTableViewSectionHeaderView") as! TravelInfoTableViewSectionHeaderView
        guard let data = data else {
            return sectionHeaderView
        }
        sectionHeaderView.cityLabel.text = data[section].name
        sectionHeaderView.arrowImageView.isHidden = false
        return sectionHeaderView
    }
}

class TipsCountriesTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    private let reuseIdentifier = "TravelInfoTableViewSectionHeaderView"

    var data: [ItineraryTipsCountry]?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: reuseIdentifier, bundle: nil)
        register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        sectionHeaderHeight = 50.0
        rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard indexPath.row == 0 else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TipsCitiesTableViewCell") as! TipsCitiesTableViewCell
            cell.tipsCitiesTableView.data = data?[indexPath.section].cities
            return cell
        }
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TipsTableViewCell") as! TipsTableViewCell
        cell.tipsTableView.data = data?[indexPath.section].tips
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeaderView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! TravelInfoTableViewSectionHeaderView
        guard let data = data else {
            return sectionHeaderView
        }
        sectionHeaderView.cityLabel.text = data[section].name
        sectionHeaderView.arrowImageView.isHidden = false
        return sectionHeaderView
    }
}

class TipsCitiesTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    private let reuseIdentifier = "TravelInfoTableViewSectionHeaderView"

    var data: [ItineraryTipsCity]?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: reuseIdentifier, bundle: nil)
        register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        sectionHeaderHeight = 50.0
        rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TipsTableViewCell") as! TipsTableViewCell
        cell.tipsTableView.data = data?[indexPath.section].tips
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeaderView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! TravelInfoTableViewSectionHeaderView
        guard let data = data else {
            return sectionHeaderView
        }
        sectionHeaderView.cityLabel.text = data[section].name
        sectionHeaderView.arrowImageView.isHidden = false
        return sectionHeaderView
    }
}

class TipsTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    private let reuseIdentifier = "TravelInfoTableViewSectionHeaderView"

    var data: [ItineraryTip]?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: reuseIdentifier, bundle: nil)
        register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data?[indexPath.row].text
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.poppinsFont(ofSize: 12.0)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeaderView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! TravelInfoTableViewSectionHeaderView
        guard let data = data else {
            return sectionHeaderView
        }
        sectionHeaderView.cityLabel.alpha = 0.48
        sectionHeaderView.cityLabel.font = UIFont.poppinsFont(ofSize: 13.0)
        sectionHeaderView.cityLabel.text = data[section].title
        sectionHeaderView.arrowImageView.isHidden = false
        return sectionHeaderView
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self sizing tableview inside self sizing tableview cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216791/self-sizing-tableview-inside-self-sizing-tableview-cell)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set constant height to inner `UITableView`. Add observer for "contentSize" of tableView. You will notified as content size is changed. So you can set `tipsCountriesHeightConstraint` here.

Add observer in `awakeFromNib` of `TipsCountriesTableViewCell` class as below,

```
tipsCountriesTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Observe value as below,

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let obj = object as? UITableView {
        if obj == self.tipsCountriesTableView && keyPath == "contentSize" {
            if let newSize = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize {
                tipsCountriesHeightConstraint.constant = tipsCountriesTableView.contentSize.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remove observer in `deinit`

```
deinit {
    self.tipsCountriesTableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}
```

You must have top, bottom constraints for `TipsCountriesTableViewCell` items.

Comment: Thanks @Komal Goyani for quick response. I have added observers to all cells and it looks more good but still some cell is missing.. here is the result imgur.com/a/GwFmuAU

Comment: Means, Can not scroll down? @BekaGelashvili

Comment: @Komai Goyani yes

Comment: If you set constant height to main tableView than you need to put that main tableView in a scrollview. @BekaGelashvili

Comment: @komai Goyani only main table is scrollable

Comment: You need to check constraints again. It needs top - bottom constraints of inner tableviews, cell items in short everywhere. @BekaGelashvili

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199241/discussion-between-komal-goyani-and-beka-gelashvili).

Comment: i have checked and it seems ok

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate the size of top level UItableView cell heights by something like this,

```
            var size = CGSize()
            let cell = YourUITableViewCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = data?[indexPath.row].text
            let fitting = CGSize(width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 1)
            size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(fitting,
                                                            withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
                                                            verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority(1))
            return size.height
```

If UILabel is custom then you need to set the bottom Constraint of UILabel to view with less than 1000 priority.